# Sharepoint webparts - Custom user control generated as base UserControl in the .designer.cs file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, user-controls, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to develop a web part for Sharepoint 2010.

I've created a user control which I want to include in my web part. However, when I drop the user control in MyWebPart.ascx (in design view) it gets generated as follows in the MyWebPart.ascx.designer.cs:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.UserControl customUserControl;
```

instead of:

```
protected global::FullNamespace.ControlTemplates.MyUserControl customUserControl;
```

It works, but I need to cast `customUserControl` to the concrete MyUserControl in the code behind (e.g. if want to set some of its properties in the PageLoad event).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

So far, my solution is declare `protected global::FullNamespace.ControlTemplates.MyUserControl customUserControl` in `yourpage.cs`. So it can get the actual type correctly.

The is easiest "solution" I think. However I still feel ugly and weird.

If you've got a better solution, please share it with me.